# save data to Django models on different types of messages I receive on Mqtt

Tags: python, django, mqtt, paho

My goal is to save data to my Django models on different types of messages I receive on MQTT. For that, I assume I need to import the model I want to save. But when I do I get "Django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet."

My MQTT connection setup: mqtt.py

```
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt
from print.views import *

def on_connect(client, userdata, rc, properties=None):
    client.subscribe("foo/printers/#")
    print("Connection returned result: " + mqtt.connack_string(rc))


def on_message(client, userdata, msg):
    handle_msg(msg.topic, msg.payload)

client = mqtt.Client()
client.on_connect = on_connect
client.on_message = on_message

client.username_pw_set(username="foo",password="bar")


client.connect("mqtt.foo.de", 1883, 60)
```

My `__init__.py`:

```
from . import mqtt
mqtt.client.loop_start()
```

My Messagehandler view:

```
from models import Machine
def handle_msg(topic, message):
    
    printer = topic.split("/")[2]
    print(Machine.objects.get(Name=printer))
```

When I put the import inside the function it simply doesn't work

Comment: Shouldn't you import your mqtt module (I mean, import functions, and all related stuff) in your Django app and then save data in the models, rather than importing Django models in your mqtt module? Or maybe I did not understand your question

Answer (score 0):

You need to setup django app first before you can import them.

Add this before the import:

```
import django
django.setup()

from print.views import *
```